# Vuejs + Laravel router redirection issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

After login, page should redirect on dashboard component and it does but then again redirect on laravel app url

[image]

**Route : I have used Vue Router**

```js
const routes = [{
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'uDashboard',
        component: uDashboard
    }];
```

**On Form Submit**

```js
methods: {
        submit: function() {
            axios.post('api/login', this.form).then(response => {
                if (response.status == 201) {
                    this.$router.push({name: 'uDashboard'});
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to add `Event` as a parameter and `preventDefault` before the axios method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your code prevent the default action on form submit like so:

```
methods: {
        submit: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // <-- added this
            axios.post('api/login', this.form).then(response => {
                if (response.status == 201) {
                    this.$router.push({name: 'uDashboard'});
                }
            })
        }
    }
```